# In the Bash prompt, why does Control+x and Backspace clear the current line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I discovered this by mistake: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Does anyone know why this clears the line? Any documentation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. From `man bash`:

> ```
>    Killing and Yanking
>        kill-line (C-k)
>               Kill the text from point to the end of the line.
>        backward-kill-line (C-x Rubout)
>               Kill backward to the beginning of the line.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This is the equivalent of a cut in Windows. You can paste it back with Ctrl+Y.

Comment: I didn't even know that Bash has clipboard-like functionality! Nice to know!

Comment: It's actually the magic of readline.

Comment: True but the end result is about the same.

Comment: @timbrigham: Yes, but it means that it also works in other programs using readline, and for those that don't, you might be able to use `rlwrap`.

Answer (score 3):

As noted, it is in the man page. More precisely, the key-combinations in question are from EMACS, which is the default key-binding for Bash in a number of Linux distributions. If you need to use vi instead under Bash, you can use:

```
set -o vi
```

To switch it back to EMACS:

```
set -o emacs
```

Answer (score 2):

`bash` supports something called the [`readline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readline) library, which allows you to do a completely amazing number of things with your shell. One of those things is that `readline` comes configured with a [large number of default keyboard shortcuts](http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts), such as:

```
Ctrl-b  Move the cursor one character   ⇦ to the left
Ctrl-f  Move the cursor one character   ⇨ to the right
Alt-b   Move the cursor one word    ⇦ to the left
Alt-f   Move the cursor one word    ⇨ to the right
Ctrl-a  Move the cursor     ⇤ to the start of the line
Ctrl-e  Move the cursor     ⇥ to the end of the line
Ctrl-x-x    Move the cursor      ⇤⇥ to the start, and to the end again
Ctrl-d  Delete  the character   underneath the cursor
Ctrl-u  Delete  everything  ⇤ from the cursor back to the line start
Ctrl-k  Delete  everything  ⇥ from the cursor to the end of the line
Alt-d   Delete  word    ⇨ untill before the next word boundary
Ctrl-w  Delete  word    ⇦ untill after the previous word boundary
Ctrl-y  Yank/Paste  prev. killed text   at the cursor position
Alt-y   Yank/Paste  prev. prev. killed text at the cursor position
Ctrl-p  Move in history one line    ⇧ before this line
Ctrl-n  Move in history one line    ⇩ after this line
Alt->   Move in history all the lines   ⇩ to the line currently being entered
Ctrl-r  Incrementally search the line history   ⇧ backwardly
Ctrl-s  Incrementally search the line history   ⇩ forwardly
Ctrl-J  End an incremental search
Ctrl-G  Abort an incremental search and restore the original line
Alt-Ctrl-y  Yank/Paste  arg. 1 of prev. cmnd    at the cursor position
Alt-.
Alt-_   Yank/Paste  last arg of prev. cmnd  at the cursor position
Ctrl-_
Ctrl-x
Ctrl-u  Undo the last editing command; you can undo all the way back to an empty line
Alt-r   Undo all changes made to this line
Ctrl-l  Clear the screen, reprinting the current line at the top
Ctrl-l  Clear the screen, reprinting the current line at the top
Completion  TAB Auto-complete a name
Alt-/   Auto-complete a name (without smart completion)
Alt-?   List the possible completions of the preceeding text
Alt-*   Insert all possible completions of the preceeding text
Ctrl-t  Transpose/drag  char. before the cursor ↷ over the character at the cursor
Alt-t   Transpose/drag  word before the cursor  ↷ over the word at/after the cursor
```

Here's some [good information on customizing `readline`](http://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/e6l5l/short_guide_to_custom_bashreadline_key_bindings/) as well.